# ¿Para que sirven los dos puntos (:) al declarar una función en PHP?

Tags: php, php7

Estoy acostumbrada a emplear la siguiente sintaxis genérica para definir una función personalizada en una clase de PHP:

```
public function my_function(arg1, arg2, ...)
{
    //Cuerpo de la función, con o sin retorno
}
```

Recientemente he visto un fragmento de un código que tenía una función definida con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
public function my_function(arg1, arg2, ...): array
{
    //Cuerpo de la función, con o sin retorno
}
```

He buscado en la documentación de PHP y en Google, y no he encontrado una explicación clara de qué hace la parte `: array` en la declaración de la función, ni por qué está ahí, ni nada concreto.

¿Alguien sabe de que va esto, o cómo funciona?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eso se conoce como **Declaración de Tipo de Retorno**, es un nuevo tipo de sintaxis introducido en PHP 7, para declarar que el tipo de dato que retorna el método (en este caso un *array*).

```
public function my_function(arg1, arg2, ...): array
{
    //el resultado de la función se enviará como array
}
```

Esto no solo se limita a *arrays*, puedes emplear `int`, `float` incluso tus propias clases:

```
class MyClass { }

function something(): MyClass {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

Estos no son solo para facilitar la lectura. Si la función devuelve un tipo diferente al indicado, el valor se convertirá en el tipo indicado. Si no se puede forzar, o el modo estricto está habilitado, se generará un `Type Error`.

Información obtenida de:

[Colon after method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40346754/4832311)

Para mas información puedes revisar la documentación:

[Declaraciones de tipo de devolución](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)

Comment: Para mas información complementaria véase esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295261/para-que-sirven-los-dos-puntos-al-declarar-una-funci%c3%b3n-en-php#answer-295276)

Answer (score 4):

Desde PHP 7 se puede definir en la declaración de una función el tipo de retorno que esperas. En tu caso, por ejemplo, espera que se devuelva un array, y si no es así puede llegar a lanzar una excepción TypeError.

Fuente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Answer (score 2):

Complementando lo ya mencionado, recuerda que también a los argumentos les debes declarar un *tipo de dato*, para que de este modo el intérprete reconozca no solo que valor va a retornar la función, sino que además sepa que tipo de valores espera como argumentos de la función; de este modo:

Esto funcionaría por que le indico que espere una cadena como argumento y le paso una cadena cuando invoco a la función:

```
function elementos(string $elemento): array
{
    return array($elemento);
}

var_dump(elementos("hola"));
```

Salida:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "hola" }
```

Sin embargo si aún declarando que el elemento de de salida de la función sea un arreglo, pero yo le paso como argumento un valor distinto al esperado (una cadena), obtendré una salida funcional como esto:

```
function elementos(string $elemento): array
{
    return array($elemento);
}

var_dump(elementos(23.90234));
```

Imprimirá:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "23.90234" }
```

Para el caso anterior, si esta regresando un vector, pero no con los valores esperados, para este caso debemos al inicio, después de la etiqueta de apertura, declarar la siguiente directiva:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
```

Con lo cual si tratamos de repetir la ejecución nos dará

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to elementos() must be of the type string, float given, called in [...][...] on line 10 and defined in [...][...]:5
>   Stack trace:

Mientras que si las intenciones son:

- Retornar un vector de valores
- Llenar dicho vector con múltiples valores de entrada de distinto tipo

Entonces pudiera quedar así:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

function elementos(string $elemento1, int $elemento2): array
{
    return array($elemento1, $elemento2);
}

var_dump(elementos("hola", 1));
```

Cada elemento es identificado haciendo referencia al tipo de dato esperado *aunque estos son distintos*, pasando dichos argumentos a la función obtendremos:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(4) "hola"
  [1]=> int(1)
}
```

Mientras que se de nuevo uno de los dos argumentos no respeta el tipo de dato esperado, aunque indiques que el retorno sea un vector, nuevamente tendrás un **Fatal error** referido a lo ya mencionado.

**Documentación**

- [Declarado estricto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict)